# query multiple columns with different condtions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with `date` column and 3 different other columns: `X`,`Y`,`Z`.
I want the get the `date`,`X` and `Y` for last month and `z` column the sum for all the previous dates.

This is the query that I worked on

```
SELECT date,
  x,
  y,
  (
    SELECT z
    FROM Table
    WHERE date < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE())
  )
FROM Table
WHERE date BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND
      DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE());
```

Here is a sample data:
[image]
and here is how I want the result to be like:

```
date       | X | Y | Z
-----------+---+---+---
2019-08-01 | 8 | 8 | 12
```

the `date`, `X` and `Y` only for last month and `Z` the sum of all time (1+1+2+8=12)

I get the following error in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Not sure what is confusing about that error. Your subquery is returning more than 1 row. I would suggest you read [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for why between is not a good choice, especially with dates. And also [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) to read about why using date part abbreviations is not great.

Comment: so how would you do the query , im lost

Comment: Well...what value do you want for z?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

No data, hard to give you a solution, but my suggestion is use following query, which will give you last month of X, and Y, at same time give you all z based on condition

```
select 
(select Top 1 X from table where ... order by ... desc) AS X, 
(select Top 1 Y from table where ... order by ... desc) AS Y,
Z
FROM table
WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this result what you are looking for?

```
    SELECT date, x, y, z FROM Table
WHERE date BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
            AND
            DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE());
UNION ALL
SELECT date,x,y,z FROM Table WHERE date < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()))
```

As all others suggested, providing sample data and expected output would help more.